# With jQuery, is it possible to have it detect a certain link class, and open them all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, automation

Say there's a button I want to click on, or a link, and there's ten of them per page and I want to control/command click them all so they load in new tabs. I do this every time, so I want to automate it. Is there a way for jQuery to target these specifically (I know how to do this), and then have them open them all in a new tab? Or is that out of jQuery's abilities?

I was thinking of making a variable for all the elements, then looping through the length of this array variable, and "control/command" clicking all of them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to simulate user clicks on the links once you get the jQuery reference to them like this:

```
$("a.selectorClass").click();
```

The links themselves can specify that they open in a new window or tab, but which one is up to the user's browser preferences.  I don't believe jQuery can control where those windows open.

Answer (score 3):

I would think something like this might work:

```
$('a.class').each(function(i, obj) {
  window.open(obj.href);
});
```

As long as they have `href` attributes, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function(){
      window.open($(this).attr('href'),'_blank');
    });
});
```